# неожиданное поведение php

Tags: php

доброго времени суток. объясните, пожалуйста, почему

```
var_dump("любая строка" == 0);
```

возвращает

```
bool(true)
```

при этом если 0 привести к строковому или булеву типу, либо использовать жёсткое сравнение, то условие отрабатывает нормально(`false`). как так получается что 0 равен любой строке? php 5.6.30

Comment: Первая строка первого примера http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)

> В случае, если вы сравниваете число со строкой или две строки,
>   содержащие числа, каждая строка будет преобразована в число, и
>   сравниваться они будут как числа.

[Преобразование в число](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

> Значение определяется по начальной части строки. Если строка
>   начинается с верного числового значения, будет использовано это
>   значение. Иначе значением будет 0 (ноль).

Соответственно при сравнении `"строка" == 0`, `строка` преобразуется в число `0`

Answer (score 1):

Потому что "любая строка" приводится к int. А int от неё - 0.

Но 0 равен не любой строке. Попробуйте "123любая строка"

Жесткое сравнение сначала сравнивает типы.

Comment: Да, в соответствии с http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: Строка приводится к целочисленному только если целочисленное необходимо в контексте

Comment: @rjhdby В смысле? В контексте операции сравнения строки с числом,строка будет приведена к числу.

Comment: В том смысле, во фразе `Потому что "любая строка" приводится к int.` ни слова про сравнение.