# Сравнение нуля и строки с помощью == в PHP

Tags: php, if

Почему условие `if ((int)0 == 'string')` возвращает `true`?

Comment: Потому что `"php" == 0`, но `"php" !== 0` http://php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [неожиданное поведение php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717618/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-php)

Comment: var_dump((int)'string');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'string' приводится к (int), т.к. в сравнении участвует число. А т.к. в 'string' нет цифр, она приварнивается к 0.

[тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/259497/) и [тут](https://coder-booster.ru/learning/php-beginners/comparison-operators) читайте.