# foreach выводит лишний элемент

Tags: php

Добрый день! Подскажите почему цикл выводил 1 лишний элемент

```
$arr = array("name" => "Маша","name2" => "Паша","Генадий","Валера", "кофе", 
"чай","8 утра");

foreach($arr as $key => $elem){
if($key == "name"){
    echo $key." ".$elem . "<br>";

}
```

}

выводит: name Маша
            0 Генадий

Comment: Ответ из той же оперы `"php" == 0, но "php" !== 0` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717618/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-php

Answer (score -1):

В случае, если вы сравниваете число со строкой или две строки, содержащие числа, каждая строка будет преобразована в число, и сравниваться они будут как числа. Эти правила также распространяются на оператор switch. Преобразование типов не происходит при использовании === или !== так как в этом случае кроме самих значений сравниваются еще и типы.

Поэтому

```
  var_dump(0 == "a"); // 0 == 0 -> true
    var_dump("1" == "01"); // 1 == 1 -> true
    var_dump("10" == "1e1"); // 10 == 10 -> true
    var_dump(100 == "1e2"); // 100 == 100 -> true
```

В вашем случае произошло сравнение 0 == 'name'